# How to start leakcanary with shell script without using Gradle command

Tags: android, performance, memory-leaks, android-instrumentation, leakcanary

How to start automation leak detection with leakcanary for android instrumentation using shell script without using Gradle.

If the instrumentation test is started by an android studio, it's working fine. But not working if started by the shell command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `leakcanary.FailTestOnLeakRunListener` as a test listener. If you're running a command like `adb shell am instrument` you can pass in a `listener` parameter to the runner listeners, ie `-e listener leakcanary.FailTestOnLeakRunListener`.

See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/runner/AndroidJUnitRunner#typical-usage